# Identify similar contents in encrypted data?

Tags: encryption

Is it possible to compare two ciphertexts (two different encryption algorithms are used to create ciphertexts) to identify redundancy?

Comment: Not if either is secure. If you're interested in deduplication under the same cipher, look into Deterministic Authenticated Encryption ([DAE](https://ia.cr/2006/221)).

Comment: It depends if you asking about such identification in a proper encryption scheme (answered by Gilles) or if you wonder if a scheme can be broken in such way that allow this (look at ECB mode and famous penguin: https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin/ ).

Answer (score 3):

Not if the encryption algorithms work. And not even if it's the same encryption algorithm. This is a consequence of one of the properties required for an encryption algorithm to be considered secure: [ciphertext indistinguishability under chosen ciphertext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#IND-CCA1). If an adversary can send ciphertext 1 for decryption, and from that learns something about ciphertext 2 (such as a similarity in their corresponding plaintext), then this property is violated.